# How to resolve Nginx "proxy_pass 502 Bad Gateway" error

Tags: nginx, x509certificatevalidator

I have trying to add proxy_set_header in my nginx.conf file. When I try to add proxy_pass and invoke the URL it throws 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.11.1 error.

Not sure how to resolve this error:

```
upstream app-server {
    # connect to this socket
    server unix:///tmp/alpasso-wsgi.sock;    # for a file socket
}

server {
    server_name <name>;

    listen 80 default_server;

    # Redirect http to https
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
    server_name <name>;

    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    recursive_error_pages on;

    location /azure{
        proxy_pass http://app-server;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/server.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional;
}
```

Comment: What do the nginx error logs say?

Comment: For this No error message is shown in error log file.

Answer (score 14):

Had similar problem with proxy_pass, if your Linux server is using SELINUX then you may want to try this.

```
$ setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
```

Refer to Warren's answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196907/proxy-nginx-shows-a-bad-gateway-error

Answer (score 2):

`502` is sent when your upstream is not reachable.

Try to switch on `error log` and you might see `failed to connect to upstream`,
for this you need to check whether your `upstream` server is running or not, `sudo service upstream status`, and try to switch that on.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx proxy with unix socket troubleshooting:

1. Check nginx conf:

```
nginx -t
```

2. Check socket:

```
netstat --protocol=unix -nlp | grep alpasso-wsgi.socket
```

3. Check is app working:

```
curl --unix-socket /tmp/alpasso-wsgi.sock http:/your-path-on-app
```

(Must be html code on screen output)

4. If not, check your app. If yes:
5. Check nginx error log

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

6. In case you get a nginx permissions error, check nginx user rights for socket:

Determine which username nginx use:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

And, for example, if nginx user is www-data, give to www-data user required rights. Add www-data user to required group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G your-socket-file-group www-data
```

and check permissions of a socket file,
or use ACL:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX /path-to-your-unix-socket
sudo setfacl -Rd -m u:www-data:rwX /path-to-your-unix-socket
```

7. Im my opinion, ACL is better for security. Because you give rights to nginx only to one file, not for all files which belongs to group.