# How to enable CORS in Nginx proxy server?

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors, reverse-proxy

As my title, here is the config file located in conf.d/api-server.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.localhost;

  location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://api.localhost';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

The nginx.conf file stay the same as default.

After I send request to api.localhost (api.localhost/admin/login), I still receive 405 error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.localhost/admin/login. Response 
to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://admin.localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

[image: That is the response from server]
[image: That's the request looks like]

Comment: You have not mentioned if you are facing any issue if yes then what the issue is?

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani I still receive 405 error when I try to send request to api.localhost, I don't know why

Comment: I tried the comment from <Tarun Lalwani> and it didn't work for me with following error: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include' until i changed this line: add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true'; to: add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The issue is that your if condition is not going to send the headers in the parent in `/`. If you check the preflight response headers it would be

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.13.3
Date: Fri, 01 Sep 2017 05:24:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Content-Type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
```

And that doesn't give anything. So two possible fixes for you. Copy the `add_header` inside if block also

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.localhost;

  location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://api.localhost';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://api.localhost';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

Or you can move it outside the location block, so every request has the response

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name api.localhost;

   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://api.localhost';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

  location / {

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

If you only want to allow certain locations in your config for CORS. like `/api` then you should create a template conf with your headers

```
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://api.localhost';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
```

and then use

```
include conf.d/corsheaders.conf;
```

in your `OPTIONS` block and `/api` block. So CORS are only allowed for the `/api`. If you don't care which location for CORS then you can use the second approach of moving core headers to server block

Comment: This time the response become 502 bad gateway

Comment: Is the 502 response means the CORS problem has been solved and the new error is about the API server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153493/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-qwang).

Comment: Problem solved, here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183357/how-to-resolve-nginx-proxy-pass-502-bad-gateway-error), thanks for your help

Comment: This worked great, but I didn't see the CORS headers for some of the requests, as the response code from the application was not within the allowed range. I added 'always' at the end of the CORS lines, per [Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) and all was golden.

Comment: after nearly two days of researching this worked for me. Sadly i can only give a single upvote - but i wish merry christmas :)

Comment: This is great, but an explanation of why the OP's approach doesn't work as expected would be appreciated.

Comment: @Roddy, i clearly mentioned that in my answer. OP's approach used if condition to add headers, while the outer headers don't get applied inside that if condition, so the PREFLIGHT request has no desired headers.

Comment: Thanks. I know (from experience!) that the headers outside the `if` don't work, but I have no idea why that is. I've never used nginx `if` before...

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't work for me, I get the following error:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Code in my nginx config can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/alex-r89/329adf48df118cffc79456e88cd377e6

Comment: @alexr89, you need to run `nginx -T` and add the whole config as a gist

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hi, running that command is successful (no errors), and that is the whole config

Comment: @alexr89, i will suggest post a new question and post the link to that question here

Comment: From what I can see, duplicating headers is [not necessary](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/5db70bbceebe13afa242ff6b4dc41cff). They are inherited. And `nginx-1.10` was released in [2016](https://nginx.org/2016.html).

Comment: As a note, I needed to know when the server returned status codes other than 200 and this wasn't working for me BECAUSE, NGINX needs the `always`parameter to add headers on "non successful" status. According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header): If the always parameter is specified ..., the header field will be added regardless of the response code. So if you're looking for this behavior, solution is to add `always` at the end of the CORS `add_header` directives

Comment: That may be the reason I had to add it twice orignally as a 204 was being returned and I had not used always

Comment: Don't forget to add `always` to add_headers so the headers are being added for non 2XX responses.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simpler configuration. When the browser sends a preflight request (OPTIONS), asking the server if it's okay to send a cross-origin request, you can set up NGINX to skip this test by returning a status of 204 for all OPTIONS requests. This will prevent future CORS checks for your YOURINTERNALIP:YOURPORT. It's important to clarify that this approach will simply suppress the preflight request.

Here is the config:

```
server {
    server_name YOURFULLDOMAIN.COM;
    location / {
        # Return 204 for preflight requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            return 204;
        }
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization' always;
        # Proxy config
        proxy_pass http://YOURINTERNALIP:YOURPORT;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache;
    }
    listen 80;
}
```