# Http-Requests blocking

Tags: c#, angular, ajax, asp.net-core-5.0, preflight

We have an angular application that makes requests to our .NET Core 5 Api. We noticed that the requests sometimes seem to be blocking each other.

So when I open a page in one browser which makes fewer requests, and open another page in another browser which make more requests (At the same time), the requests from the first page seem to be only completing after the requests of the second page have been completed. So the first page is taking too much time to load and seems to be "blocked".

When I load the pages separately the requests from the first page complete much faster.
We noticed that the preflight seems to be taking a lot of time, if we make requests simultaneously:
[image]

The actual request will start after the preflight and therefor is deferred. Why does the preflight take so long? Is there a way we can analyse this further? Are there any known issues?

Edit:

I tried the solution from [My Cors Preflight Options Request Seems Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56332753/my-cors-preflight-options-request-seems-slow).
But the actual requests still seem to be blocking eachother. So it doesn't seem to directly relate to the preflight request.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56332753/my-cors-preflight-options-request-seems-slow) ?

Comment: I have tried this by adding the cors headers in web.config and handling it with IIS. The preflight doesn't take that long anymore but the actual requests still seems to be blocking each other.