# Is it okay to use "if" for setting CORS headers?

Tags: nginx, cors

The [common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994114/52499) to handling CORS requests is as follow:

```
location ... {
    add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin       ...;
    add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials  ...;
    add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Headers      ...;
    add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Methods      ...;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin       ...;
        add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials  ...;
        add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Headers      ...;
        add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Methods      ...;
        return 204;
    }
}
```

But [`if`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) is [evil](https://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html). Is it safe to use it this way?

**UPD** By the way, from what [I can see](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/5db70bbceebe13afa242ff6b4dc41cff), the duplicate `add_header`'s are not needed.

Comment: It’s OK. From the http://nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil page cited: *“There are cases where you simply cannot avoid using an `if`, for example, if you need to test a variable which has no equivalent directive”* & has a when-it-can’t-be-avoided example that’s functionally identical to the case in the question: `if ($request_method = POST ) {  return 405; }` So the answer is: You can’t avoid it for this case. That doesn’t make it “safe” as far as lacking the risk http://nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil describes— but just that there’s no real alternative

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `if`. Take several `map`s (outside of `location` or `server` block -> works only in `http` block).

```
map $request_method $one
{
    default '…';
    get '…';
    options '…';
    post '…';
}

map $request_method $two
{
    default '…';
    get '…';
    options '…';
    post '…';
}

map $request_method $three
{
    default '…';
    get '…';
    options '…';
    post '…';
}

map $request_method $four
{
    default '…';
    get '…';
    options '…';
    post '…';
}
```

Strings are matched ignoring the case. As long as it's not a normal regex.

The first parameter of the `map` is the input (in this case `$request_method`). Depending on the match, a new variable is created in the second parameter of the map (in this case `$one`, `$two`, `$three`, `$four` (which you can name as you wish)) with the matched `'…'` content.

```
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $one';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: $two';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: $three';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: $four';
```

Untested.

Comment: You're forgetting the `return` statement. And why `more_set_headers`?

Comment: Oops, right. Because I always use it - it is more intelligent. But are you sure that you need `return 204` at all? For example, if I query with `curl -I`, no content is sent with it. I checked with Wireshark.

Comment: Not exactly need, the network etiquette obliges :) If seriously, you might be right, or not. It's hard to confirm. You can check if this (response `200` for `OPTIONS` requests) causes no issues in the common browsers. But you can't be 100% sure it works for everyone. Most likely you can find some user agent if you look hard enough for which it doesn't. And by the way I don't understand what kind of requests you were making, and what that proves.

Comment: You are right. `curl -I` only queries the headers (`HEAD`). Better would be `curl -i -X OPTIONS https://www.google.com/`.  However, I only get a 405 Not Allowed.