# Cors error on spring boot connecting it with react and trying to deploy on tomcat or jboss server?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, nginx, cors

I have a react application that is deployed on NGINX running on 9000 port successfully.

Then I have my spring boot war file deployed on tomcat server 9xx on port **8081**.

And I have already enabled/added global cors in spring boot but still facing this issue.

**As I have analysed I am not getting any response headers back from the server.**
[image]

In spring boot main class I have added this

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedHeaders("*").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000").allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
```

**And allowed from http://localhost:9000 server**

Request from browser fails with cors error, in this my preflight request is successful
[image]

As my spring boot deployed on 8081
[image]

And my NGINX configs
[image]

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I am stuck at it from last 7 to 8 hours.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986631/how-to-enable-cors-in-nginx-proxy-server/45994114#45994114

Comment: The CORS configuration for the port 9000 nginx server isn’t relevant. It definitely has nothing to do with the error message cited in the question. The request is being sent from frontend JavaScript code (served from the port 9000 server) to the port 8081 Spring server. So as far as CORS configuration goes, the only thing that matters is the CORS configuration on the port 8081 server. So you probably want to update to question to change the title and to remove the details about the nginx CORS configuration. Those are just a distraction from trying to identify the actual cause.

Comment: would [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application) help with spring boot setup?

Comment: I am assuming that you are not making the requests from the same machine on which you have your setup while answering. Your allowed origin is incorrect. Please use "*" for now instead of "http://localhost:9000". Let me know if that works.
If you want to restrict origins, you should do so via domains. Origin specifies the origin of the request, not what you specified.

Comment: @timur NO as I am not using spring secutiry

Comment: @MukulBansal, I am all my setup on 1 machine (Local Environment) and "*" does not work as I have used with credentials true. And have already tried it with various combinations.

Comment: @John have you annotated your configuration class appropriately? like this-

`@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}`

Reference- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Comment: I have added cors function inside main class, so no need of that. 

So inside main class annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Try to explicitly provide your allowed Headers and Methods. Sometimes useing '*' causing errors. If this not help you can provide a `CorsWebFilter` Bean.

Answer (score -2):

You can avoid CORS using proxy_pass. Configure your NGINX to proxy(forward) all the requests with URIs starting with '/api/' to the spring boot located at localhost: 8081.

```
upstream springboot_service {
    server localhost:8081;
}

location /api/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://springboot_service/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
```

Comment: @AjeetShah, but spring boot is not attaching response headers back, I checked, I think therefore this error is comming

Comment: @John You should retry with [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=spring%20boot%20cors) and [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/). If it still doesn't work, I would suggest that you create a new spring boot project following that (official) tutorial to understand it better. There is no way other than as explained in those answer and tutorial. Try with simple and fresh projects; that would be easiest way to debug it.

Comment: @AjeetShah, preflight request is successful, but actual request fails

Comment: @AjeetShah, can help me out by connecting..., Please I am stuck at it for days now

Comment: @AjeetShah I was successfully able to deploy resolve the cors on local environment as well as When I tried to deploy on production tomcat server. But still facing CORS issue wit h, JBOSS EAP 7.3 server.