# How to add a Website in a ReactJs responsive web app?

Tags: reactjs, webview

I need help with this problem. My objective is to put a website inside a ReactJs web app. I tried using the `iframe` of ReactJs, it does not work.

Is there a way to use React Native WebView component inside a **ReactJs** web app?
Or is there a Webview Component in **ReactJs**

I do want the end-user to jump to another tab in order to use the website. I want them to continue to stay in the ReactJs web app and use the website.

The website that I am putting is a .Net website and I am doing a ReactJs project, not a React Native Project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

simply using iframe should work as this exemple (source below)
since your giving an url to this iframe langage doesn't matter if it can be served in http(s)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <iframe src="https://<website>/" />;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

As said in source the src url should be embeddable to be used inside an iframe if not you can use a reverse proxy to serve this url and change headers

source:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/best-practices-in-using-iframes-with-react-6193feaa1e08

Comment: Hi, much thanks for the answer. i had tried this iframe method and i also followed this source as well. I came across the issue which the x-frame of the source website is set to "sameorgin" and i dont think its embedable. if using this iframe method, how to solve this issue? else is there any method which does not include iframe?

Comment: As said in source the src url should be embeddable to be used inside an iframe if not you can use a reverse proxy to serve this url and change headers

nginx for instance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986631/how-to-enable-cors-in-nginx-proxy-server