# CORS error between Python-Flask and Web-App on managed docker server (different sub domains)

Tags: javascript, python, docker, flask, cors

This issue has been slowly driving me insane.

The error I get is the famous CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://backend.apps.company.com/hello' from
origin 'https://frontend.apps.company.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Basically, I am building a simple web-app, trying to separate out the backend from the frontend. The FE will likely end up being a vue app, whereas the BE is written in Python and Flask.
Both will be hosted on the same managed docker-server. However, the way our department has set up the server results in a different sub domain for each container, and also means that I only see the CLI logging, and do not see any other logs beyond that.

**This is the relevant portion of the python code:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["CORS_HEADERS"] = "Content-Type"

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "https://apps.company.com"}})


@app.route("/hello")
@cross_origin(origin='apps.company.com',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
def hello():
```

**This the frontend JS that gets executed on click:**

```
async function testClick(){
    
    let headers = new Headers([
        ["Content-Type","application/json"],
        ["Accept", "application/json"]
    ]);

    let request_get = new Request("https://backend.apps.company.com/hello",{
        method: "Get",
        headers: headers
    });


    let response = await fetch(request_get);
    let result = await response.json();
```

The code might not be the prettiest (due to reassignment I have not really coded in almost 1.5 years, so I am very rusty), but it works as tested locally.
The dockerfiles do not do anything fancy, other than installing pip packages for python, and to replace the nginx.conf for the frontend to use port 9080, as our docker-server did not like port 80 being used.

**Frontend Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY html /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 9080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**And nginx.conf:**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen 9080;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        server_name    localhost;
    }

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I have tried every conceivable combination of flask_cors. The simple `CORS(app)`, the general `@cross_origin()` decorator, the general resources/origins `cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})`.
In fact, at least on local host I could verify that all these approaches work. When I run my flask container locally without the flask_cors package, trying to access it from a different port on local host throws the CORS error. Even if I run both containers locally, both with a different exposed port, the API call only works if flask_cors is included in backend.

That leads me to believe there must be something on the managed docker server itself creating this issue. Could it be the subdomains? Or something else entirely?
As said, I do not have access to the containers themselves. But if I knew what to look for specifically, I could get some time with one of the platform engineers to look into it (I hope).

Thanks!

Edit:
I should add that I spent two days going through every available SO, reddit, docker-forum, or other posts that related to CORS and docker, tried out multiple changes in the CORS handling in flask, all to no avail.

*Log for other things I have tried:*

- attempted to contact hosted server-container via curl within company network --> got a login redirect
- check OPTION response when trying to access hosted server-container from hosted FE-container --> OPTIONS response is empty, got a 502 error
- set flask_cors debugging level, as I do have access to a modified CLI --> works locally, but the output does make it to the CLI in the hosted environment.

My current assumption is that the host server uses a reverse proxy or similar to direct traffic, and that proxy sets the CORS policy, which I would not have any control over. It's worth reiterating that the server is not a standalone docker-server, but a managed All-in-one solution for App hosting within our corporate network. Stands to reason that there are multiple layers between the actual container and the environment. Oh what fun...

Comment: does the server respond with appropriate CORS headers for the pre-flight?

Comment: @JaromandaX I just updated the post to reflect. It does so locally, which I can see in the flask logger. However, when I push it to the environment, I can no longer see the flask logger, and the OPTIONS response is empty, when trying to connect to the server-container from my FE-container

Comment: In [this answer](/a/77060234) I discuss setting up a reverse proxy for a multi-container application.  If your front-end application is served via the proxy, and calls the back-end via the proxy, then it's a same-origin call and the CORS rules shouldn't apply.  Would a setup like that help you?

Comment: @DavidMaze that sounds intriguing! I will give this a try. My suspicion is that on the server there is already a proxy running that facilitates traffic, which is out of my reach. But hopefully I am wrong.
So this solution of yours, the proxy would be inside the front end container?

Comment: Try `@cross_origin(origin='https://apps.company.com',headers=['Content-Type','Authorization'])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a similar structure, I mean separating the frontend(react+ts+webpack) and the backend(py+flask).

I have met this CORS problem, what I did is use a **reversed proxy** in the frontend, every request sent to `https://frontend.apps.company.com/api` first, then this proxy redirects the request to the backend `https://backend.apps.company.com/`, and the problem addressed.

I didn't use nginx, I used the express server for the frontend, But, I think you can configure in a similar way. (maybe you should search something like cors nginx, link:[How to enable CORS in Nginx proxy server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986631/how-to-enable-cors-in-nginx-proxy-server))

I just checked my codebase I have this in the flask

```
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

it seems this is important as well