Nginx + React + Django: Understanding CORS Request Headers
I'm hosting a React frontend app and Django backend API on Nginx in a single local Raspberry Pi, on ports 80 and 8000, respectively, with the following config:
// REACT APP
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /link-to/build;
        index index.html;

        server_name pinode;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}

// Django APP/Gunicorn
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /link-to/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}

For my use case, I'd like all internal requests between react and django to use localhost. However, the user can access the react front end using the Raspberry Pi's hostname (in this case, http://pinode/ as seen in nginx config above).
In react, all API calls use http://localhost:8000/api/*.
During my testing of the above, I had some level of success. However, one of the following always fails exclusively:

During login, I get a response from http://localhost:8000/api/login/, but the Set-Cookie fails due to Cross-Site policy.

Attempting to add headers to nginx backend config results in requests being rejected due to CORS policy.

Post requests are rejected due to a missing csrftoken, despite axios is setup with X-CSRFToken header and tested in development environment.


I didn't seem to find a comprehensive tutorial showcasing what configuration is ideal for settings.py, axios, and nginx to make things work. Appreciate some help.

Have you considered passing through OPTIONS from nginx to the api?

I'm not sure I get it. Can you please refer me to a link that might help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986631/how-to-enable-cors-in-nginx-proxy-server
This would help

You might want to try out the django-cors-headers library. Here is a basic configuration that might be useful for you:
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://pinode"
]


This configuration allows the addresses "http://localhost" and "http://pinode" to access your Django application. django-cors-headers is a highly useful library when you are dealing with Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in a Django project.
However, it's important to remember to add corsheaders to your INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE in your Django settings, as shown below:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]


It's important to note that CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is always related to the origin of requests. In this case, you always need to allow CORS for your React application, which is the origin of your requests. This means that the server where your Django application is running needs to include your React application's URL in the CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS list, which allows the React application to make cross-origin requests to your Django server.
I hope this can help you! If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

I've added the origin (i.e. pinode) to the allowed CORS origins in settings.py, but seems like NGINX misses things in the process.

Hello, I would recommend trying to remove nginx and running Django with runserver to verify if the headers are being returned on the response header. This could help in diagnosing the issue.
