# How do I select a resolver in nginx?

Tags: nginx, resolver

cat /var/log/nginx/error.log

> *644181 no resolver defined to resolve

website shows

> 502 Bad Gateway

I read these:

- [What does the Resolver param in nginx do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330704/what-does-the-resolver-param-in-nginx-do)
- [502 Bad Gateway - NGINX no resolver defined to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937222/502-bad-gateway-nginx-no-resolver-defined-to-resolve)
- [How to resolve Nginx "proxy_pass 502 Bad Gateway" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183357/how-to-resolve-nginx-proxy-pass-502-bad-gateway-error)
- https://distinctplace.com/2017/04/19/nginx-resolver-explained/

---

I've discovered that I need to set a resolver variable for nginx, but I still can't seem to figure out what it should be set to.  Many answers seem to throw out a random IP without any explanation as to how they got that.

Any information on this subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it seems to be 127.0.0.1 -> https://serverfault.com/a/973311/547377

---

In docker it may be 127.0.0.11

> Note: for docker, it's DNS resolver resides at 127.0.0.11, so...

found in the comment section here: https://serverfault.com/a/593003/547377

---

127.0.0.1 worked for me